# How to select the first row for every sub group using a custom order?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

Having a Table Person

[image: Sample of table Person]

and a Table PersonRecord

[image: Sample of Person Record]

I need to select only one record for each person, the record with the max status.
The status are ordered by `C > B > A`, a person can have multiple records with different or the same status, I need always select the greater status or the first (if the person have records with the same status).

I make the following query to get the rows ordered

```
select ep.personid, ep.persondesc, records.veryimportantcode, records.status
    from extperson ep
    left join 
    (
      select rownum as rn, v.* from
      (  
        select pr.personid, pr.veryimportantcode, pr.status
          from personrecord pr
        group by pr.personid, pr.veryimportantcode, pr.status
        order by pr.personid,
          decode(pr.status,
          'C', 1,'B', 2,'A', 3,
          4)
      ) v
    ) records
    on ep.personid = records.personid
```

it give me:

[image: Data ordered]

I need

```
|PERSONID   |PERSONDESC|VERYIMPORTANTCODE   |STATUS |
|00325465   |Bjork      |(null)             |(null) |
|00527513   |Paul       |ZP-2143540         |A      |
|00542369   |Hazard     |ZH-7531594         |C      |
|0324567    |Jhon       |ZJ-2346570         |B      |
```

I try to achieve this using an aditional materialized subquery where I count the number of repetitions and make a left join with a `where (subquerymat.nrorepeat > 1 and rownum = 1) or (subquerymat.nrorepeat = 1 or subquerymat.nrorepeat is null)` but does not work.

There is one very important rule for this query, I would append this query in the right side of an union inside a view then I can't use stored procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select personid, persondesc, veryimportantcode, status
  from (select pe.personid,
               pe.persondesc,
               pr.veryimportantcode,
               pr.status,
               row_number() over(partition by pe.personid order by pr.status desc,
                                                                   pr.autoid) as rn
          from person pe
          left join personrecord pr
            on pe.personid = pr.personid)
 where rn = 1
```

**Fiddle test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25074/2/0

Comment: ORA-00904: "RN": ungültiger Bezeichner
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @florian.isopp do you have a question? If you get that error then presumably you do not have the analytic function shown above in your inline view. There is in fact a column named `rn` returned by the above inline view.